# WPF DataGrid binding cell's to data model with dynamic columns

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I've got a data model that can be considered as a table with dynamic columns and rows.

The model exposes a collection that defines the columns that currently exist.
Each column is an object (a model) itself.
The model also exposes a collection containing the rows. Also each row is a model representing the row.

Each row exposes a collection that contains the column values. Each column "value" is a model too.

```
MyModel
    - Columns (list of MyModelColumn)
    - Rows (list of MyModelRow)
    
MyModelColumn
    - Header (string)
    - ...

MyModelRow
    - Values (list of MyModelCell)
    - ...
    
MyModelCell
    - CalculatedValue
    - DisplayValue
    - Color
    - ...
```

What I would like to achieve is:

- A `DataGrid` that has columns dynamically created, corresponding to `MyModel.Columns`
- Each cell in the `DataGrid` must be able to bind to properties of the corresponding `MyModelCell`.
- Each `DataGrid` column is a `DataGridTemplateColumn`.

It seems to be not too hard, but I tried several different approaches and still can't get it done.

I managed creating `DataGrid` columns dynamically (from codebehind).

The `DataGrid`'s own behavior makes each cell in a `DataGridTemplateColumn` have
its `DataContext` set to the "data item" that belongs to the whole row. In this case, the `DataContext` of each `DataGrid` cell is a `MyModelRow` instance.

The `DataTemplate` for the `DataGrid` cell knows about the `MyModelRow`, and can bind to properties on that class directly, but that's not what I want. I want to bind to the corresponding `MyModelCell` that belongs to the row/column.
From within the CellTemplate (and CellEditingTemplate) you can never determine in what column the cell is, and so you don't know
which `MyModelCell` (from `MyModelRow.Values`) you have to access to read a property of the `MyModelCell`.

The main problem is: how to connect each cell in the DataGrid to the MyModelCell it belongs to?

My data model classes I'm talking about are viewmodels, and the problem is mainly UI related. So, using codebehind is fine, and maybe even unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

> The main problem is: how to connect each cell in the DataGrid to the MyModelCell it belongs to?

Since the `DataContext` of a `DataGridRow` is always the current item of type `T` in the `IEnumerable<T>` sequence that the `DataGrid`'s `ItemsSource` property is set or bound to, you will have to include the index of the cell in the binding paths in the `CellTemplate` and `CellEditingTemplate`, e.g.:

```
Binding="{Binding Values[0].CalculatedValue}"
```

...for the first column.

This means that you will have to (preferably programmatically) create a separate template for each column where you replace `[0]` in the binding path(s) with the index of that column's cell.